# System.TypeLoadException on Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm running an asp.net 4.6 app on the app service. Just removed mvc from the site and using url rewrite to run an mvc free angular spa with a webapi.

Now it's asking for a type that was renamed months ago and works in pre mvc removal builds. I don't think it's got something to do with mvc though.

In trying to solve this I've xeroxed my local bin folder onto the server and the error still persists. So some sort of server config?

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are using a type which is not found in your assembly. To troubleshoot this issue, you need to find where you used this type. I suggest you use the Find in files feature provided by Visual Studio by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F. After found the place which used the type, you just need to delete it and rebuild your application.

[image]